# In strategy.exit and strategy.entry, errors occur in current_so and strategy.position_size when I use stop and limit

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

In strategy.exit and strategy.entry, errors occur in "current_so" and "strategy.position_size" when I use stop and limit. I will be glad if you help me.

The codes are below.

```
var current_so = 0
threshold = 0.0



// Average Down
if (current_so > 0 and strategy.position_size > 0 and current_so <= max_safe_order and previous_high_value == 0.0 and (bar_index - entryIndex >= Mum_araligi))
    if safe_order_step_scale == 1.0
        threshold := initial_order - initial_order * price_deviation * safe_order_step_scale * current_so
        threshold
    else
        threshold := initial_order - initial_order * ((price_deviation * math.pow(safe_order_step_scale, current_so) - price_deviation) / (safe_order_step_scale - 1))
        threshold
        strategy.entry('SO ' + str.tostring(current_so) + '@' + str.tostring(source_function(source_type)), direction=strategy.long, limit = (threshold), qty=(strategy.position_size < 0) ? ((strategy.position_size * (-1)) + (math.round(((capital_function(capital_type) * safe_order / 100 ) * math.pow(safe_order_volume_scale, current_so - 1) / source_function(source_type)), 2))) : (math.round(((capital_function(capital_type) * safe_order / 100 ) * math.pow(safe_order_volume_scale, current_so - 1) / source_function(source_type)), 2)), alert_message = (str.tostring(usdBase)) )
        current_so += 1
        current_so
        entryIndex := bar_index 
// Stop loss
if  (strategy.position_size > 0) and (low < long_beakeven) 
    strategy.exit("L Stop",  from_entry = 'Long @', stop = (long_start_breakeven == 1) ? long_beakeven : stop_loss_level, comment= SELL )
    previous_high_value := 0
    original_ttp_value := 0
    original_ttp_value
    take_profit_level_on := 0
    current_so := 0
```